# Filtering objects based on another object in js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filer out items in arr1 that match the key of items in arr2
My code seems right but its not returning the correct values for me.

**it should return:**

```
arr1 = [{x: 'LEFT_SPRING'}, {x: 'LEFT_OPEN'}]
```

But instead its doing this:

```js
    const arr2= [{x: 'LEFT_INDEX'}, {x: 'LEFT_MIDDLE'}]
    
    const arr1 = [{x: 'LEFT_SPRING'}, {x: 'LEFT_INDEX'}, {x: 'LEFT_OPEN'},{x: 'LEFT_MIDDLE'}].filter((item) => arr2.some((s) => item.x!== s.x))
    
    console.log('arr1 = ', arr1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `filter` condition will always return `true` because there always be `some` records in `arr1` not equal to the current record in `arr2`, the `filter` condition should be `.filter((item) => !arr2.some((s) => item.x === s.x))`

```js
const arr2 = [{
  x: 'LEFT_INDEX'
}, {
  x: 'LEFT_MIDDLE'
}]

const arr1 = [{
  x: 'LEFT_SPRING'
}, {
  x: 'LEFT_INDEX'
}, {
  x: 'LEFT_OPEN'
}, {
  x: 'LEFT_MIDDLE'
}].filter((item) => !arr2.some((s) => item.x === s.x))

console.log('arr1 = ', arr1)
```

Comment: Ah thank you I knew it was something simple I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `every` with `!==`, or (`!`) `some` with `===`.

```js
const
  arr2 = [
    { x: 'LEFT_INDEX'  },
    { x: 'LEFT_MIDDLE' }
  ],
  arr1 = [
    { x: 'LEFT_SPRING' },
    { x: 'LEFT_INDEX'  },
    { x: 'LEFT_OPEN'   },
    { x: 'LEFT_MIDDLE' }
  ]
    //.filter((item) => !arr2.some((ref) => ref.x === item.x)); OR
    .filter((item) => arr2.every((ref) => ref.x !== item.x));
    
console.log('arr1 = ', arr1)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: hmm I didn't think about it this way. Thanks

Comment: @me-me Check out [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and [discrete mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_mathematics).